# sending instance of the current class to another as a parameter

Tags: c#, class, parameter-passing

I am looking for this Java code's equivalent in C#

```
public class MainClass {

    public MainClass() {
        OtherClass o = new OtherClass(this);    //I am looking for "this" keyword to send the instance
    }
    public void someMethod() {

    }
}

public class OtherClass {

    public OtherClass(MainClass m) {   //and this receiver method
         m.someMethod();
    }

}
```

I think there should be a way **in C#** to sent the current class as a parameter so that I can call the **someMethod()** in **MainClass** from **OtherClass** ?
How can I do that in C#?
Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking for this Java code's equivalent in C#

Well, no equivalency needed. Your code is already a valid C# code without any modification. Here is a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/foGkk9).

Note: I would be very worried about the circular reference in your code, but I'm sure it was just a simple sample and you wouldn't actually implement code like that.

**Important Note:** Just to be clear, you are not sending the "class". That's just not possible. You are sending an **instance of the class**. Maybe that's what you meant, but just so nobody reads it and get confused.

Comment: Interestingly, it worked. How did I get so blind... Anyway thank you

Comment: Btw thanks for correction. I got it! next time I ll use the "instance" :)